# Combine a DB with git?

Tags: sql, database, git, version-control

Goal is to query a file by its unique id from a database. But additionally this file should be under version control to have the option of using a different/former state of it.
Is that possible at all?

Use case is to use that file as action instruction, in other words as a testcase, e.g. to test a new software. The testframework queries this testcase by its id. So far so good. But the challenge is now to be able to possibly test a former software version with the corresponding testcase state. So this implies to run both, db and vcs.

Or is there any alternative to a db? Mandatory is to refer to the testcase by an id.

Comment: "Database" *usually* implies some sort of binary file, and those are always finicky with source control. In particular, merges will become problematic if binary files change in both branches, then you usually have no other option than to take one of the files and lose the changes introduced in the other branch. Is there any way to *build* this database from source files as part of the build process?

Comment: Could you for instance simply store the testcases as raw json or xml files on disk and use the "id" as the filename?

Comment: Using simply the filename is no option: there are different apps to test on the system under test, depending on which one is activated. For example, if app A is activated, we  test it with tc1. When app B is activated it has to be tested with its own testcase tc1. - So there are several equally named testcases with slighlty different contents. The development of the software and the test environment are separated, so the test environment is not part of the build process of the software.

Comment: The testcases are csv-files.

Comment: If you need them in a database for quick lookup I would do the building of that database, from the csv files, as part of the build process. This way you can add the csv files to the git repository and not the database. csv files are text, which git excels at processing.